# Congruence equation proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Proof that $\forall{a}\in\Bbb N \rightarrow a^3\equiv a\mod (a+1)$

I do not know how to prove these equations.

I only know that $a\equiv m \mod b \implies m | ( b- a ) \implies b-a=m\times k $ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$

So (...)

$(a+1)-a^3 \implies (-a^3+a)+a(-a^2+1)+1=a\times k$

But I can not take it from here.

I wish comeone could help me to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We have (Not as you said) 
$$a\equiv m \mod b\iff b|(a-m)$$
and since 
$$a^3-a=a(a^2-1)=a(a-1)(a+b)$$
can you take it from here?

Comment: $0\mod (a+1)\implies a(a-1)0 = 0$?

Comment: Just right! Not too much, not too little! +1

Answer (score 1):

$$a^3-a=a(a^2-1)=a(a+1)(a-1)\equiv0\pmod{a+1}$$